Alpha Beta pruning with passes
How would the basic alpha beta pruning algorithm look like if a player has no legal moves and must pass its turn to its opponent? (if neither player had legal moves then the game finishes and the search shall return the payoff of the position)
Thanks in advance
Here's the basic:
function alphabeta(node, depth, α, β, Player)         
    if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
        return the heuristic value of node
    if Player = MaxPlayer
        for each child of node
            α := max(α, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player)))     
            if β ≤ α
                break // Beta cut-off
        return α
    else
        for each child of node
            β := min(β, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player)))     
            if β ≤ α
                break // Alpha cut-off
        return β

// Initial call
alphabeta(origin, depth, -infinity, +infinity, MaxPlayer)

the problem is that I'm not clear on how to recurse, by max or min if turn is same.
my guess is like:
function alphabeta(node, depth, α, β, Player)         
    if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
        return the heuristic value of node
    if Player = MaxPlayer
        for each child of node
            α := max(α, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player)))     
            if β ≤ α
                break // Beta cut-off
        if no children // a pass, player plays again.
            α := max(α, alphabeta(node, depth-1, α, β, Player))     
            if β ≤ α
                return α

        return α
    else
        for each child of node
            β := min(β, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player)))     
            if β ≤ α
                break // Alpha cut-off
        if no children // a pass, player plays again.
            α := min(α, alphabeta(node, depth-1, α, β, Player))     
            if β ≤ α
                return β // Beta cut-off

        return β

// Initial call
alphabeta(origin, depth, -infinity, +infinity, MaxPlayer)


Basically you allow the side to move to make two consecutive legal moves. It is generally called the null move heuristic and can help prune the game tree considerably. It hinges on the usually true (but not quite always) that the player to move can always improve his position by making a move. It goes wrong badly for zugswang positions in chess.

Your pseudo code is not explicit enough. As it stands, the recursive call in the case of no children would lead to infinite recursion. You'd better include the notion of making a move somewhere. Also the minimizing and maximizing cases are not well mirrored.

Need not be infinite, it's passing depth-1 and depth =0 is a stop condition

OK, not infinite, but you'll not progress: it is the same state over and over again until you're out of depth.

If passing the turn is a legal move, then the position after a pass is a legal position and should be searched as normal.

The problem in your second piece of pseudo code is that:

In case if no children is true, the recursive call will get the same node and player, and so there is no progress in the game state: recursion will end when depth reaches zero and a heuristic value is returned for the state where no follow-up moves (by the same player) were made.

The code for the two if no children cases is not mirrored correctly. In the second (minimising) case you actually allow α to becomes less than it was.


A common approach is to consider that scenarios where the same player gets to play more than once in a row are often interesting variants in the sense they might well lead to a scoring that is on the extreme side (either high or low). And then we could decide to always finish the complete, combined moves for the concerned player for as long they get to continue, regardless of the depth, and to count such sequences of moves as one, combined move. This will work well for games like Othello and Mancala, for instance.
So, you would use the standard version of the alphabeta algorithm, but change the way the move generator works. Something like this:
function get_descendent_nodes(node, Player)
    node_list = new empty list
    for each child of node for Player
        if child has no children for not(Player)
            extend node_list with get_descendent_nodes(child, Player)
        else
            append child to node_list
    return node_list

This function will check whether the opponent has no valid moves, and will in that case get next moves for the current player and only collect the final nodes where that player cannot continue like that anymore (either because of reaching a terminal node or a node where the opponent has moves).
Use this in the standard alphabeta algorithm:
function alphabeta(node, depth, α, β, Player)
    if depth = 0 or node is a terminal node
        return the heuristic value of node
    children = get_descendent_nodes(node, Player)
    if Player = MaxPlayer
        for each child of children
            child = apply move on node
            α := max(α, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player)))     
            if β ≤ α
                break // Beta cut-off
        return α
    else
        for each child of children
            β := min(β, alphabeta(child, depth-1, α, β, not(Player)))     
            if β ≤ α
                break // Alpha cut-off
        return β

See also an implementation I posted in answer to How do I fix this minimax algorithm for Mancala?
